# How can I simulate User Input in a JUnit Test?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have the following code to test:

```
public IGrid createIGrid() {
    while(size < 0){
        userInput();
    }
    GridArray gamefield= new GridArray(size);
    return gamefield;
}

public void userInput(){
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die größe des Grid an. Der Wert muss größer als 0 sein.");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();
    if (size < 1) {
        throw new ImpossibleValueForArrayException();
    }
}
```

Now I want to test it. What can I do?

Comment: Well, you've got a `Scanner` there - you can create a `new Scanner("The string you want to input")`, and it returns the tokens from that. So just create the `Scanner` with the input you want, and inject it.

Answer (score 0):

you could simulate an call of an function.

```
public class Core {
    private static HandleInput handleInput = new HandleInput();
    public static void main(String[] args)  {   
        handleInput.getConsoleInt();
    }

    @Test
    public void test()  {
        handleInput.handleInput(74);  // your testing number
    }
}
```

And for the Input Handler:

```
class HandleInput {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public int getConsoleInt()  {
        return  scanner.nextInt();          
    }
    public void handleInput(int input)  {
        if (input < 1) {
            throw new ImpossibleValueForArrayException();
        }
    }
}
```

but you could do it with the `Robot.class`... but thats very costly...

Answer (score 0):

Use Mockito framework in conjunction with JUnit, so you can mock `scanner.nextInt()` and define the expected value to return.
If you are not familiar with Mockito, I would recommend to read this article http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html